# gmap api v3 infowindow html string content not showing

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've a problem with pushing array html content into an infowindow:
I whant to try to append a html string for each marker that i customize via javascript into the Map, the code work with a native infowindow, but when i try to append html the infowindow is empty.

Here the code:

```
function initialize(markerPlaces) {
    (function(window, google, maplib){
        var mapOptions = maplib.MAP_OPTIONS,
        domElement = document.getElementById('map'),
        //map declaration
        map = new google.maps.Map(domElement, mapOptions);
        console.log(markerPlaces);
        var contentStringOpen = '<div class="modul1 modalWindow">';
        var contentStringMiddle = '<span class="modul1_txt">';
        var contentStringClose = '</span></div>';
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var contArray = new Array();
        for(i=0;i<markerPlaces[0].posts.length;i++){
            var thumb = markerPlaces[0].posts[i].thumb;
            var title = markerPlaces[0].posts[i].title;
            contArray.push('' +
                    '<div id="' + markerPlaces[0].posts[i].postId +
                    '" class="modul1 modalWindow">' +
                    markerPlaces[0].posts[i].thumb +
                    '<span class="modul1_txt">' +
                    markerPlaces[0].posts[i].title +
                    '</span></div>');
            markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {
                    lat: Number(markerPlaces[0].posts[i].lat),
                    lng: Number(markerPlaces[0].posts[i].long)
                },
                map: map,
                icon: 'http://tovisit.today/wp-content/themes/turisti/img/poi.png',
                title: markerPlaces[0].posts[i].title
            })
            console.log(contArray[i]);
            google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', (function(markers, i) {
                return function() {
                    //switch this for htmlContent
                    //infowindow.setContent(contArray[i]);
                    //this work
                    infowindow.setContent(contentStringMiddle + markerPlaces[0].posts[i].title + contentStringClose + markerPlaces[0].posts[i].thumb);
                    infowindow.open(map, markers);
                    $()
                  }
                })(markers, i));
        }
    }(window, google, window.maplib || (window.maplib = {})));
}
```

The content string is correct:

[image: firebug output]

but when i ispect the dom the div.modalWindow, and his content, missing

[image: map output]

anyone has the same trouble?

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem, sometime a display:none cause some trouble, i forgot this debug css line, i apologize for loosinrg your time.
The function is correct and work by the way.
Thank U for the -1 have a nice day